# estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath doesn't update row height

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have multiple dynamic cells with a different row height. So, I am trying to update row height with a method estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath

This is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        return 132
    case 1:
        return 66
    case 2:
        return 80
    case 3:
        return 70
    case 4:
        return 50
    case 5:
        return 60
    case 6:
        return 60
    default:
        return 60

    }

}
```

But, row height doesn't update. It's using estimated row height from Storyboard. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In youre case you should use method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Use `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` when you would like to use auto resized cells.

> Providing an estimate the height of rows can improve the user
>   experience when loading the table view. If the table contains variable
>   height rows, it might be expensive to calculate all their heights and
>   so lead to a longer load time. Using estimation allows you to defer
>   some of the cost of geometry calculation from load time to scrolling
>   time.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
   switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        return 132
    case 1:
        return 66
    case 2:
        return 80
    case 3:
        return 70
    case 4:
        return 50
    case 5:
        return 60
    case 6:
        return 60
    default:
        return 60

    }

}
```

Comment: Ohhhh!!!! I am so inattentive! Thank you very much, Oleg! You saved a lot of my time!! :)

Comment: "Use `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` when you would like to use auto resized cells." ... No, you use this (or better, just set the estimated row height for the table, itself), whenever (a) you have rows of different heights (when you implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is actually a typical use-case); but (b) you don't want it to calculate actual heights for all the rows that might not yet be visible. Now, in this case, if there are only six rows visible, it doesn't matter. But if there are lots of rows that are not visible, one might also set the estimated height.

Comment: @Rob thx I was using estimatedHeight only for autoresize cells. Thx for sharing you're experience.